# Typescript Vue, keyof Ref object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following reactive object

```
type Players = Ref<{ 1: Player, 2: Player }>

const players: Players = ref({
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Player 1',
        questionIds: [],
        modifierIds: []
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Player 2',
        questionIds: [],
        modifierIds: []
    }
})
```

Now I'm trying to type a selected item from that object, Trying this with

```
const activePlayerId = ref<keyof Players>(1)
```

Or I've tried

```
const activePlayerId = ref<keyof Ref<Players>>(1)
```

I'm getting the following error `TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Players'.`

Comment: FWIW, it's more conventionally done with an array and .find. You're duplicating id field as hashmap key, not a good sign.

Comment: I can omit the id field, are there other benefits to using an array?

Comment: It's more straightforward to use for an undertermined amount of elements and when you need to traverse an array, e.g. find a key for player object. It's unknown if it's two player game like chess in your case or it can change at some point. And the problem here is that the key is not 1 number but '1' string. You'll have to constantly convert types. In case you don't want id and always have 2 elements, I'd just use a 2-element array (tuple) and zero-based index

Comment: Good points, thanks. The player number will always be 2. (Which means the array doesn’t even have to be reative, right?) only the items in the array.

Comment: Possibly yes, there's no need to be reactive, but it's easier to keep it reactive rather than not. Basically it's `const player1 = ref(...); const players = reactive([player1, player2])`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing types and values.

```
const activePlayerId = ref<keyof Players>(1); // Would only return the type of the player, which is always Player
```

Rewrite as follows:

```
const players = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Player 1",
    questionIds: [],
    modifierIds: [],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Player 2",
    questionIds: [],
    modifierIds: [],
  },
]);

const activePlayerId = ref(1);
```

If you track the id of the active player separately, the code is simpler and more maintainable. You would get the active player this way:

```
const activePlayer = computed(() => players.value.find((player) => player.id === activePlayerId.value));
```

If you are certain that there is always one player selected, you can type the following to tell TypeScript that it cannot be undefined:

```
computed(() => players.value.find(...) as Player)
```

Comment: Thanks, the only issue I have now is that in all my computed properties I'm getting the warning "activePlayer.value is possibly undefined" because of the find method